# Cotensor and counit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra, coalgebras

If M is a C-bicomodule, then considering C as a $C$-bicomodule also, is $M \square_C C \cong C$, where $\square_C$ is the cotensor product in $^C\mathscr{M}^C$.

Comment: Are you trying to circumvent the questions-per-day quota?

Answer (score 2):

Of course not, we have $M \square_C C = M$. The proof is the same as for modules (in fact, the statement holds in great generality in monoidal categories, and statements about monoidal categories can be dualized).